# bash script errors in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: bash, scripts

I wrote a script whilst on ubuntu 12.04.5 which ran through fine however after upgrading to 14.04.2 to fix another issue i am now having issues with the script.

It is halting at the first set of commands and i cannot seem to identify why; i made amendments based on google results however each change results in more errors.

The part of the script its currently stalling at is

```
#!/bin/bash

V=1.5.4

DELAY=3

if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2

    sleep 5
   exit 1

fi

while [[$REPLY != 0 ]]; do

    clear

    cat <<- _EOF_

        Please Select:

        1. Menu option 1
        2. Menu option 2
        3. Menu option 3
        4. Menu option 4
        5. Menu option 5
        6. Menu option 6
        7. Menu option 7
        0. Exit

    _EOF_
    read -p "Enter selection [0-7] >"

if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[0-7]$ ]]; then

        if [[ $REPLY == 1 ]]; then
```

When I run the above script using `sudo ./config.sh` I receive the error

```
./config.sh: line 23 [[: command not found
```

When i remove the extra brackets i receive the error

```
./config.sh: line 23: [: !=: unary operator expected
```

In the full script the line containing while `[[$REPLY != 0 ]]; do` is line 23

Adding quotes to `$Reply` also results in the same error.

I don't understand what has changed within bash since upgrading to the newer LTS. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you make the code block containing all of your script's text? Looks horrible... Just indent all of the lines (even the empty ones).

Comment: Also note that its better to use `while [[ $REPLY -ne 0 ]]` while comparing numerics..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a space between `[[` and `$REPLY`:

```
while [[$REPLY != 0 ]]; do
```

should be

```
while [[ $REPLY != 0 ]]; do
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick responses to this; i cannot believe it was as simple as adding a space between the brackets and the variable.

Comment: You are welcome, and I would appreciate if you accept my answer if it solved your problem (click on the tick below the vote up/down arrows on the left).